# Pre/Post Increment with overflow in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a UInt8 that is used as a sequence number and is incremented each time it is used. The problem occurs when I try and increment the number from 0xFF to 0x00. Apparently Swift does not automatically process the overflow but instead throws an error.

I have read that to do an increment/decrement with overflow you have to use the &+ and &- operators, but this does not seem to work with pre/post increment/decrement operators.

```
var sequence:UInt8 = 0
...
array.append(sequence++) // overflow error on this line
```

It is not a big deal if I have to split this into two lines of code, but I was just wondering if there was a way to accomplish this without having to do the following:

```
var sequence:UInt8 = 0
...
array.append(sequence)
sequence = sequence &+ 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own wrapping postfix increment operator:

```
var sequence: UInt8 = 0xFE

postfix operator &++ { }

postfix func &++<T: IntegerType>(inout x: T) -> T {
    let tmp = x
    x = x &+ 1
    return tmp
}

sequence&++  // returns 0xFE
sequence&++  // returns 0xFF
sequence&++  // returns 0x00
sequence&++  // returns 0x01
```

Comment: That is pretty interesting! But would that still increment after the append() takes place? I am just surprised something like this is not already built in. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it’s written to post-increment, that’s why it takes a tmp copy of the value before adding 1.  pre-increment wouldn’t need to do this, it would just add one and return that.